# How to choice appropriate material in 3D model

Tags: three.js

- Hello,
- I have an issue about coloring the models. Here is my 3D model result: (Please be patience for the loading time around 5 seconds)
  https://yan-wei-yu.github.io/threetest/test.html
- As you can seen, my scan model color is not good as it in the first pic(orange color) and my jawbone color isn't good as the teeth color in the second pic as well
- It seems like that I need to adjust some parameters such as diffuse, specular, texture material...etc. But I have no idea how to do it in three.js.
- Appreciate for your patience and helps.
- Best regards
- [Good pic orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKoo5.jpg)
  [Good pic gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qh87.jpg)
  [My test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXfKO.jpg)

The last is my code:
Github code:https://github.com/Yan-wei-yu/threetest/blob/main/test.html

Comment: You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*